# Writing a Macro to Use the Transpose Function for strings of text

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to move rows of text into one column in Excel that's in a new Sheet. The transpose function works well, but will only move one row at a time. I would like to get a macro that will convert thousands of rows of data across multiple columns into one column. Please see example below (I've separated each column in the row by semi-colons). Thanks in advance for any help.

Rows:

```
Avila P, 2005, CHEM ENG J; Barbero BP, 2008, CHEM ENG J; Crookes R, 2004, SERIES MAT SUS APLIC
Duran FG, 2009, APPL CATAL B-ENVIRON;  Amini SK, 2004, CHEM PHYS LETT
Ali MH, 2005, SYNTHESIS-STUTTGART; Arya P, 2001, CURR OPIN CHEM BIOL; Balunas MJ, 2008, J NAT PROD
```

Column:

```
Avila P, 2005, CHEM ENG J
Barbero BP, 2008, CHEM ENG J
Crookes R, 2004, SERIES MAT SUS APLIC
Duran FG, 2009, APPL CATAL B-ENVIRON
Amini SK, 2004, CHEM PHYS LETT
Ali MH, 2005, SYNTHESIS-STUTTGART
Arya P, 2001, CURR OPIN CHEM BIOL
Balunas MJ, 2008, J NAT PROD
```

Comment: What happens when you select all the rows and try to transpose them?

Comment: Why dont you transpose them all and than concatinate them (`CONCAT()`)? Or are you breaking the columns limitation if you do?

Comment: did you try copy/paste into a text document and then open that in excel as ; delimited?

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Missed the part about he added ;'s  My bad.  Simon's answer should accomplish what you need, or at the very least get you very close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading the question correctly I think the following code would work:

```
Dim c as Range, Rng as Range, cDest as Range
Dim x as long
Dim shOrig as worksheet, shDest as WorkSheet

Set shOrig = Sheets("NameOfSheetWithData")
Set shDest = Sheets("NameOfSheetToPasteTo")

Set Rng = shOrig.Range("A1:Z100") ' Set to range where data is held

Set cDest = shDest.Range("A1") ' Cell to start pasting data into

x = 0

For Each c In Rng
    If c.Value <> "" Then ' Skip blank cells
        cDest.Offset(x, 0).Value = c.Value
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next c
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature on Excel called "Text to Columns", which can be used to solve this kind of problem.

Select the data, Click on "Text to Columns" (in the Data tab), select "Delimited", click next, and select "Semicolon" as the delimiter in this case.

When you click Next again, the dialog will show how your result will look like. Each set will be stored in separate columns, on the same row.

The original data will be replaced with the first column, by default, unless you change the destination in the dialog.

Click Finish to view the result.

Answer (score 0):

A standard technique for writing macros using new features of the Excel Object Model, that one is not familiar with yet, is:

- *Record a Macro* in miniature;
- Then use the VBA editor to expand the macro to full size.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP is open to a slightly less than ‘head-on’ approach and is amenable to a solution via Word:

1. Copy spreadsheet data and Home > Clipboard > Paste Special into Word as Unformatted Text.
   (This automatically replaces the cell boundaries with tabs.)
2. Select, Insert > Tables > Table – Convert Text to Table with Number of columns set to `1` (Separate text at should be preset at Tabs).
3. Select result and paste back in to Excel.

Comment: This worked great too! Both the macro above and the Word  solution worked perfectly. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's a tough choice. I will accept the macro above because it's a little faster, but I do like how easy the Word solution is.